# How to Resolve Dojo wc is not defined errors

Tags: dojo

wc.render.updateContext &
wc.render.getRefreshControllerById

I am not able to use the above lines in dojo based script files. Getting script errors like  wc is not defined.

Can anyone guide me how to solve this issue.

I use these below scripts but none works
dojo.require("wc.service.common");
dojo.require("wc.render.common");

Do we need to import any required scripts to support wc?
dojo.require("wc.service.common");
dojo.require("wc.render.common");

Comment: Please provide more descriptive code and the errors you are getting when posting questions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.